# Android Studio- An exception ocurred applying plugin request [id: 'com.android.application'] The option android.injected.build.density is deprecated

Tags: java, android, gradle

Recently I have encountered this problem while trying to run a project in Android Studio. I haven`t seen it before and wasn't able to find the solution to this exact problem anywere. Anyone knows how to solve it?

PS: The full error message is the one below:

An exception occurred applying plugin request [id: 'com.android.application']

> Failed to apply plugin 'com.android.internal.application'.
> The option 'android.injected.build.density' is deprecated.
> It was removed in version 8.0 of the Android Gradle plugin.
> Density property injection from Android Studio has been removed.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by changing the gradle version to 7.6.2

[Here is the list of all the gradle releases](https://services.gradle.org/distributions/), you can trial and error with the one that works for you.

In `gradle-wrapper.properties` find this line

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.6.2-bin.zip
```

Change the gradle version here.